# TestMethod for verifying Web API calls in C# with Cache manager

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to write a test method for my AngularJS Web API calls which has application cache (Cache Manager) in the application start up. When I try to run the test method it calls the Controller and when the code reached the Business class, it is expecting the CacheManager to have the Cache in it, since the cache manager is empty as we have m=not started the application yet, it throws NULL Exception. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the API controller, need to set the config.Routes.MapHttpRoute and initialize the HTTPCONTEXT as below.

```
var Route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
            new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost", ""),
            new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
            );
            var RouteData = new HttpRouteData(Route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "unittest" } });
            var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost");
            controller.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext(config, RouteData, Request);
            controller.Request = Request;
            controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice in unit testing is to separate tested logic from dependencies which should be tested separately. The easiest method to achieve this is mocking. You can use mocked Cache Manager and inject it into your application to handle all calls which will be made during test and return predefined values. Control over how mocked interface will behave is very fine grained. From my experience I would recommend Moq mocking package.